# Downloaded images are missing bytes

Tags: android, image, download, ftp, apache-commons

My Android app (Java 8, min SDK 24, target SDK 27) downloads images from an FTP server, using Apache's `FTPClient` (version 3.6).

There are a couple of smaller .jpg images (around 12kb each) that always download completely but all of the bigger .png images (8+ mb each) show up black in my app. The files on the server look fine, so I downloaded the images from the emulator:

Windows' "Photo" app displays a black, horizontal bar at the bottom of all the affected images and they are all missing a couple of bytes (according to Windows' file explorer).

Reading the downloaded image with `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(....)` on a real device returns a `null` `Bitmap`, even though the file exists.

My code (runs on a background thread):

```
public void downloadFiles(String remoteFolder, String localFolder, ArrayList<String> filenames) {
    //login here
    ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(10000);
    ftpClient.setDefaultTimeout(10000);
    OutputStream out = null;

    try {
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); 

        if(ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(remoteFolder)) {
            for(String filename : filenames) {
                FTPFile[] singleFile = ftpClient.listFiles(filename);

                if(singleFile != null && singleFile.length > 0) { //check if file exists
                    String localPath = localFolder + File.separator + filename;
                    out = new FileOutputStream(localPath);

                    if(!ftpClient.retrieveFile(filename, out)) {
                        //Set error message here
                        out.close();
                        break;
                    }

                    out.close();
                } else {
                    //Another error message here
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //And another error message here
    } finally {
        try {
            if(out!=null) { out.close(); }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            //Doesn't matter
        }
    }

    //logout here
}
```

I tried `out.flush()` before closing the stream, a longer timeout (`ftpClient.setDefaultTimeout(30000)`) and even `retrieveFileStream`:

```
InputStream is = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(filename);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
byte[] buf = new byte[10000000];
int len;

while ((len = bis.read(buf)) > 0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
}

if(ftpClient.completePendingCommand()) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Done"); //This is always printed, even though the files aren't complete
} else {
    Log.d(TAG,"Not done");
}

out.close();
bis.close();
```

The problem persists. I added up `len` and and even ran `bis.read` a couple more times (`if(fullLength<singleFile[0].getSize())`) but no matter what, most of the time less than 10 bytes are missing in the downloaded file. Only rarely one of the images is actually downloaded completely but it seems to be pretty random.

How do I fix this, so it downloads all of the images completely?

Comment: Looks like I am having the same issue. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, not yet. The only thing that seems to make less files go corrupt is using a smaller buffer for the `BufferedInputStream` but it still happens afterwards, just less often. Please check out the [newer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62284629/2016165) question, there's much more information there, including different versions that all fail to produce 100% perfect files. What is your setup and what type of ftp server is affected?

Comment: Is it your ticket on Apache Commons issue tracker - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NET-686? For some reason, I believe it is. You can check the recently added comment there from me, where I describe my setup.

Comment: Yes, that's indeed my issue. A single information is missing: What type of FTP server is it? Windows or Linux? I noticed that with one type the problem occurs more often than with the other - I haven't worked on the app lately, so I can't remember which one it was. Did you set it up in your home network (and access it through "10.1.1.xxx"), maybe even on the same PC, or is it hosted somewhere else?

Comment: I re-wrote my code twice, so there's something you could try: 1. Use the library's sockets (check the second linked question) instead of `retrieveFile`. 2. Don't use the library at all but instead use Java's `Socket` class to download the files. With both versions the problem was still present for me. I also tested the "2." code version in a regular Java windows app (Eclipse) and everything was fine. My guess is that there's something in Android (Android Studio?) that messes with the download of files from FTP servers within the same network. I don't know what to do about that though.

Comment: The FTPS server is on a remote machine (Linux, I believe), accessed by the app via VPN (hostname of FTPS is "10.1.x.x"). Thank you for the ideas on identifying the root cause.
BTW, I tried my code on an external public FTPS - no issues. I am under impression the issue is somehow related (1) to FTPS setup (which is out of my reach) or (2) to VPN setup or (3) a combination of 1 + 2. Also, as you said, it may be Android specific for FTP in the same network.

Comment: I made additional verification. It appears it fails only if both conditions are met: (a) Android emulator + (b) VPN (or LAN, however I have not checked it specifically for a true LAN, vs VPN).

Comment: Both of the servers I tested it on are just regular FTP servers (not FTPS), one is a Linux server, the other a Windows server (I think that's the one that has the problem occur more often). I don't use a VPN but just access the servers with "10.1.x.x", as they are in the same lan network. Downloading the files from external FTP servers (a private one is FTP for sure, not sure about public ones I've tested) always results in complete files. What public FTP server did you test it with? I used "DLP Test", unfortunatly that one deletes uploaded files every 15-30 minutes - no issues with it though.

Comment: I just noticed your last post on the Apache issues post: So downloads only end up incomplete if you use Android Studio's emulator + private server but they are fine if you use an actual Android device + private server? That might be a problem with Android Studio's emulator then. I first noticed the problem when downloaded images failed to display properly on an actual device (displayed as black rectangle because the images were corrupt) but I've only used the emulator since. My guess is that you're using API 29, right? My tablet uses Android 9/API 28 but I have to use API 24 (Android 7) in AS.

Comment: My Android emulator is running on Android 10 (API 29). Yes, I don't reproduce it on my Google Nexus (Android 8.1), even if accessing the same FTPS via VPN.

Comment: If you experience data corruption on actual devices, then probably adding `out.flush()` before `out.close()` may help. From the sources and documentation it is unclear whether the `out.close()` automatically flushes pending bytes (in theory it should not, but Android has modified version of the "default" `FileOutputStream`). So worth trying.