# Use "RETR" FTP command with Apache Common's FTPClient

Tags: java, android, ftp, apache-commons-net

I'm working on an Android app (Java 8, target API=27) that downloads files from an FTP server (using Apache Common's `FTPClient`) but I'm experiencing a big [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62023585/2016165) with missing bytes with the `retrieveFile` and `retrieveFileStream` methods.

That's why I want to try the alternative of sending the actual commands:

```
//login
String path = remoteFolder + "/" + filename;

if(ftpClient.isConnected()) {
    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); //For images,...
    ftpClient.retr(path); //sends the "RETR" command

    String reply = ftpClient.getReplyString();
    Log.d(TAG,reply);
}
```

This prints:

```
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
```

But what now?

`ftpClient.getReplyStrings().length` is `1` and it's the same text. Usually I'd send the `RETR` command on the command socket, then read the data socket's reply (= the contents of the e.g. txt file) but there don't seem to be different, openly accesible sockets in this library.

**Question:** How do I get the contents of the file "manually" - so using the FTP commands but without using the `retrieveFile...` methods (if possible)?

Answer (score 0):

Before sending `RETR`, you need to send `PASV`, `EPSV`, `PORT` or `EPRT` and parse its response. Typically you would use `PASV`, for which there's [`FTP.pasv` method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#pasv()).

The next would to be open the data connection, based on the response to the `PASV` (and only then you send `RETR`).

But implementing the data connection is lot of work. And the `FTPClient` implementation of the data connection is hidden in a protected `_openDataConnection_` method. So you cannot reuse the standard implementation. You will have to use generic [`Socket` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html).

And only then you can call [`FTP.retr`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#retr(java.lang.String)) (which does not do much on its own).

---

*This is all a bad idea. But if you want to do it, check the implementation of `FTPClient.retrieveFile` – It's all there.*

*The `FTPClient.retrieveFile` and `FTPClient.retrieveFileStream` methods work perfectly – They are being used by thousands – It's probably the most widely used FTP library for Java. If it does not work for you, it's either because you are using them incorrectly or because there's something wrong with your network or servers.*